# Site visitors who submit a profile are added to a group get a 404 error instead of a confirmation screen

Tags: profile

We use several profiles that people use to signup for our newsletter, apply to volunteer, etc. They were working properly: respondents saw a confirmation screen, Contacts were created and added to Groups, notification emails were sent. Now the respondents see a 404 error instead of a confirmation screen, but all the other functionality still works (Contacts added to Groups, notification emails sent.)
The problem occurs with all the Profiles that add people to groups. This is the text that the submitters see:
"The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
If it's not obvious, we're relatively new users.
CiviCRM 5.45.0 with WordPress 5.8.3
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind adding the signup url and redirect to url(you can replace the domain with example.org to preserver the identity)? Also could you confirm if you have set 'Redirect URL' in the profile setting

Comment: All of our signup profiles results in the 404 error when the user submits the completed form. Here is one of them
https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/?page_id=1067&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fprofile%2Fcreate&gid=14&reset=1
I didn't know about setting 'Redirect URL's  in the profile setting. Until recently the interactions were working fine with the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this

1. **Easy way**

[create a Thank you for submission page](https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page) in wp with some thankyou for submitting the form message. [Edit the profile](https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fuf%2Fgroup%2Fupdate&action=update&id=14&context=group) and set the redirect to url under the 'Advanced Settings' section to thankyou page url you just created.

2. **Clean Url**

Make sure that the base page is set - go to https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1

Review the Base Page setting and value, it cannot be blank

Make sure there is a published page that matches the one in that page

If there is no value there, add one, civicrm is the default and then create a WP page with that slug

Make sure the page is public and visible to all

Once you've done that (or confirmed the base page exists) Visit this page https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Confirm that your permalinks are set to anything EXCEPT Plain

If it is set to Plain change to one of the other options and save

If it is not set to plain, you can exit the page

Flush CiviCRM Caches go to https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1 and click cleanup caches